# Registering a background task in WinRT

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, win-universal-app, background-task

I'm trying to register a background task and I'm getting some strange behaviour.  I appears that the task itself is registering and firing at the right time; however, when it does fire it's closing my program down (with no error).

I suspect that the reason is linked to the fact that the program is not asking me is I want to allow a background task to run when I launch.  I have created a declaration for the background task as a system event, and am registering like this from the App.Xaml.cs:

```
var builder = new BackgroundTaskBuilder();

builder.Name = "NewTask";
builder.TaskEntryPoint = "ConnectionMonitor.CheckInternet";
builder.SetTrigger(new SystemTrigger(SystemTriggerType.InternetAvailable, false));

BackgroundTaskRegistration task = builder.Register();
```

So, I believe my question is: why would it not ask me for permission to run a background task (which I assume will give me the answer to my main problem of why it is crashing)?

I'm not sure whether it matters, but this is a Windows Universal app (the app.xaml.cs above is in the `Shared` project.

The task looks like this:

```
BackgroundTaskDeferral _deferral = taskInstance.GetDeferral();

bool newConnected = IsConnected();
if (connected != newConnected)
{
    connected = newConnected;
    var notifier = ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier();
    var template = ToastNotificationManager.GetTemplateContent(ToastTemplateType.ToastText02);

    var element = template.GetElementsByTagName("text")[0];
    element.AppendChild(template.CreateTextNode(connected ? "Connection available" : "Connection lost"));

    var toast = new ToastNotification(template);
    notifier.Show(toast);  
}

_deferral.Complete();
```

Comment: We would need to see your ConnectionMonitor.CheckInternet.Run() implementation to understand what is going on.

Comment: I've updated it - but I had a breakpoint on the first line and it didn't hit... the app just closed down.

Comment: I suspect that you have added Declarations in manifest file and your class with Task is a Windows Runtime Component?

Comment: You suspect correctly

Comment: Try debugging with the Native debugger to see if there is a native exception being thrown.

Comment: Just a guess, but the crash is likely being caused by trying to show a toast from the background task. Generally UI elements cannot be created on background threads.

Comment: Yes - I thought of that, which was why I put a breakpoint at the start of the task... and it didn't hit.

Comment: @chuex It's worth pointing out that Toast and Tile Updates are some of the core use cases for Background Tasks and don't cause any problems. If you are interested, you can watch "Background Tasks" here: http://blog.jerrynixon.com/p/teched-2014.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You asked: **why would it not ask me for permission to run a background task?**

The answer is, unless your background task requires lock screen access, it does not require the user's permission to be registered. There is no user prompt, by design. One of the intents of this design is that it allows you to register a task from another task.

In Windows, you do not need to call `BackgroundExecutionManager.RequestAccessAsync()` except for lock screen access. Calling it will give you more quota but will require the user to approve the task.

In Windows Phone, calling `RequestAccessAsync()` is required no matter what, but never prompts the user with a UI. For this reason the logic in your Universal App can be shared but will likely have a `#if` to handle the registration differently, if relevant.

Comment: Okay - that certainly does answer my question, but it also renders my initial assumption that this is causing the background task to close the app as fallacious.